# finding consecutive numbers in a matrix with python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

[image]I am practicing some exercises and have been going in circles trying to figure it out. The first part is to create a 5x5 matrix with NumPy giving it random values, and I’ve already solved it.

Now I need to see if the matrix, either horizontally or vertically, has consecutive numbers
(for example: The matrix of the attached image does not have consecutive numbers).
Here is there are 4 consecutive numbers in the first column:
[[50 92 78 84 36]
[51 33 94 73 32]
[52 94 35 47 9]
[53 5 60 55 67]
[83 51 56 99 18]]`
Here are 4 consecutive numbers in the last row
[[50 92 78 84 36]
[41 33 94 73 32]
[72 94 35 47 9]
[55 5 60 55 67]
[84 85 86 87 18]]"

The last step is to continue randomizing the array until you find those consecutive numbers.

Comment: Why don't you iterate over these numbers and check if each number is 1 higher than the previous one?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the remaining steps (show it as properly formatted code in the question)?

Comment: Please include code and output as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a naive approach to check whether each row/column of a given matrix has a given amount (4 in this case) of consecutive numbers:

```py
import numpy as np

def has_consecutive_number(M, num_consecutive=4):

    for v in np.vstack((M, M.T)): # You need to check both columns and rows
        count = 1         # Record how many consecutive numbers found
        current_num = 0   # Recording 1 or -1
        for i in range(1, len(v)):
            diff = v[i] - v[i-1]

            if diff == 1:  # if diff is 1
                if current_num != 1: # if previous diff is not 1, reset counter
                    count = 1
                current_num = 1
                count += 1
            elif diff == -1:
                if current_num != -1: count = 1
                current_num = -1
                count += 1
            else: # reset counter
                current_num = 0
                count = 1
            if count == num_consecutive:
                return True
    return False

M1 = np.array([  [10, 43, 74, 32, 69],
                 [20, 19, 69, 83,  8],
                 [89, 31, 62, 61, 17],
                 [35,  3, 77, 22, 29],
                 [52, 59, 86, 55, 73] ])
print(has_consecutive_number(M1, 4))

M2 = np.array([  [10, 43, 74, 32, 69],
                 [20, 19, 69, 83,  8],
                 [89, 31, 62, 61, 17],
                 [35,  3, 77, 22, 29],
                 [52, 53, 54, 55, 73] ])
print(has_consecutive_number(M2, 4))
```

Output is `False` for first matrix and `True` for second matrix

```
False 
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I tried your solution and it returns True when two numbers are consecutive, how could I adjust it so that it returns True if it finds 4 consecutive numbers?

Comment: Hi @AndresDeagustini, the answer is updated